# InfoPath Forms do not open in InfoPath Filler

Tags: sharepoint-server, infopath, internet-explorer

I have a forms library in SharePoint 2010.
When some people try to open InfoPath forms it seems like the browser wants to open them in the browser and not in InfoPath filler. Since those forms are not browser enabled that does not work. For other people this works as expected.

How does the browser (or Windows) know with which application it should open the InfoPath forms? I have tried the file extensions, but this is XML and XML can be multiple things. Where can I configure that InfoPath forms should be opened in InfoPath Filler and not in the browser?

Comment: Did you use repeating tables ot repeating sections in a Form Library? If so, look into the settings.

Answer (score 0):

You define in InfoPath Designer if the form is a filler or browser enabled form. If the form is browser

Ensure that all users have Infopath installed on their machines, so they can actually open the form in Filler.

For a detailed walk through see [Specify the compatibility settings for a form template](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Specify-the-compatibility-settings-for-a-form-template-dfbcca29-ddb3-4aeb-8a57-d9dbb2e1a660)

Comment: The form is not a browser-enabled form. InfoPath Filler is installed. But the form will open in Internet Explorer anyway and then display an error message, because Internet Explorer cannot display the form). It seems like the browser does not know that it should open the InfoPath XML file in InfoPath Filler. Unfortunatelly I could not figure out how to tell it to open the form in InfoPath Filler.

Comment: check library settings and form settings. Set it to open in application